# jQuery $.getJSON and looping through array is dumping all out

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, laravel

This is my current JS code:

```
$(function(){
$.getJSON("/get_slideshow_messages",
    function(data){
        setInterval(function(){
            $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                console.log(item.message);
            });
        }, 5000);
    }
);
});
```

I am making a simply slideshow, and the call to the url is returning a Laravel eloquent object in the form of:

```
return SlideshowMessages::all();
```

If I console log 'data' the return is:

```
Object, Object, Object]
 0: 
     Objectcreated_at: null
     id: "1"
     message: "test1"
     updated_at: null
     __proto__: Object
 1: Object
 2: Object
  length: 3
```

How can I loop through the array correctly so that I only receive one item each time?

Comment: is there any issue with the loop you are trying with $.each ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep a counter which is changed each time the interval is called, rather than use an each. I haven't tested this as I don't have your dataset - but in theory this should work.

```
$(function(){
$.getJSON("/get_slideshow_messages",
    function(data){
        var currentSlide = 0;
        var nextSlide = function () {
                //Loop back around
                if (!data[currentSlide]) currentSlide = 0;
                console.log(data[currentSlide].message);

                //Increase our counter
                currentSlide++;
        }; 

        //render the first slide straight away
        nextSlide();

        //Set up our interval to render them every 5 seconds
        setInterval(nextSlide, 5000);
    }
);
});
```

Comment: Close – you just need to call the function immediately the first time, otherwise when the page loads it will wait 5 seconds before showing the first slide.